# how can access virtual directory with action link in ASP.NET MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, url, virtual-directory

I have created web application in MVC 3 and I have uploaded it to server..

Problem is this I created virtual directory and upload my project in this virtual directory its url is like this

```
www.snowads.com/snow
```

So where I use `@Html.ActionLink("Register", "Create", "User")`
its creating link like this

```
www.snowads.com/User/Create
```

but I want it should include virtual directory name

```
www.snowads.com/snow/User/Create
```

how can I do this ?

Comment: Plese see this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6360175/running-an-asp-net-mvc-app-from-a-virtual-directory-in-iis7

Comment: Is your snow directory configured as an application in IIS? It seems no as the URLs generated would include the snow otherwise.